# Froala editor show the data in html instead of edited text

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, froala

I use froala editor in rails and put the js code in application.js, so far after disabling the turbolinks, to create and edit the data using editor is working, but not for to show the data, here is my js code for the editor :

```html
$(function(){
 $('.froala-editor').froalaEditor({
 inlinemode: false,
    minHeight: '200px',
    buttons: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline','formatBlock', 'align',
              'insertUnorderedList', 'insertorderedList', 'table', 'outdent',
              'indent', 'createLink', 'html'],
    tableResizerOffset: 10,
    tableResizingLimit: 50
 })
 
})
```

and this code in slim to view the data :

```html
.fr-view 
  = simple_format(t.attribute :failure_summary)
```

bu the result come out like this

```html
Failure summary : <p>TM core break at 600m from IMEA. ff</p>
```

instead of the text edited like in editor

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a call to `raw` to tell Rails not to escape the content. Like so:

```
.fr-view 
  = raw(simple_format(t.attribute :failure_summary))
```

Just keep in mind with an editor like Froala (which has the ability to directly edit HTML) it is possible to inject some potentially dangerous code. [Rails guide on XSS](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-scripting-xss).

So if this editor is user facing I would strongly recommend you send the content through a [sanitizer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html) and only whitelist certain HTML elements (`h1`, `p`, `div`, `b`, `strong`, etc.). Make sure `script` tags are **not** allowed.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @patkoperwas, but it still not working after adding the 'raw'